# swift keychain add, delete, get working, update not working

Tags: swift, macos, keychain

I'm troubleshooting a problem with Keychain updates.  I have SecItemAdd, SecItemCopyMatching, and SecItemDelete working.  But I'm stumped on SecItemUpdate.  I always get a -50 fail.

I've put a public MacOS keychainTest project on Github at:
https://github.com/darrellroot/keychainTest/blob/master/README.md

FYI this almost identical question/answer should help me, but it's not:
[Swift 4 Keychain SecItemUpdate Error status code -50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574960/swift-4-keychain-secitemupdate-error-status-code-50)

Here's relevant code snippets:

```
let keychainTest = "Keychain Test"
let serverHostname = "mail.nowhere.com"
let keychainService = "KeychainService"
```

AddQuery works:

```
let addQuery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
kSecAttrService as String: keychainService,
kSecAttrAccount as String: serverHostname,
kSecValueData as String: inputTextOutlet.stringValue]
let status = SecItemAdd(addQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
```

GetQuery works:

```
let getQuery: [String: Any] = [
kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
kSecAttrService as String: keychainService,
kSecAttrAccount as String: serverHostname,
kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
kSecReturnData as String: true]
var rawResult: AnyObject?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(getQuery as CFDictionary, &rawResult)
statusLabel.stringValue = status.description        
guard let retrievedData = rawResult as? Data else { return }
guard let pass = String(data: retrievedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return }
```

DeleteQuery works:

```
let deleteQuery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                  kSecAttrService as String: keychainService,
                                  kSecAttrAccount as String: serverHostname]
let status = SecItemDelete(deleteQuery as CFDictionary)
statusLabel.stringValue = status.description
```

But for this updateQuery I always get a -50 OSStatus message:

```
let updateQuery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                  kSecAttrService as String: keychainService,
                                  kSecAttrAccount as String: serverHostname]
 let newAttributes: [String: Any] = [kSecValueData as String: inputTextOutlet.stringValue]
 let status = SecItemUpdate(updateQuery as CFDictionary, newAttributes as CFDictionary)
```

per osstatus.com, -50 is "One or more parameters passed to the function were not valid."

Comment: What's the type of `inputTextOutlet.stringValue`? Try `inputTextOutlet.stringValue ?? "dummy"`

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var inputTextOutlet: NSTextField!       inputTextOutlet.stringValue is a String.         If inputTextOutlet becomes nil for some reason (it won't in this case) this would crash rather than give error -50.   The compiler warns me that using the nil-coalescing operator has no effect because left side is not optional.  Thanks for the suggestion.